# Rails authorization: Can I just add a before_filter for all actions? without using Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I am about to implement authorization for my Rails app.
I know I can use Cancan, but in my case all the roles I have are: user and admin. I see that people always secure the models with roles (like cancan does).

My take on authorization would be to just add:

```
 before_filter :redirect_if_not_admin :only => :create, ...
```

and then:

```
def redirect_if_not_admin

       if !@user.is_admin?
            redirect_to :root  
end
```

in all my controllers and the actions I want to restrict from being accessed.

Q1. Is this in any way less secure than restricting the access to the models' attributes?

Q2. Is there a way for someone to bypass the before_filter and the redirect and access my controller code?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -- just add the `before_filter` and your redirect handler method in `application_controller.rb`.  As long as your user model has a method "is_admin?" this will work fine.

It is as secure as any other method (in fact, it *is* the method used in most cases like this).  The only way to bypass the before filter would be if your code allowed it.  Indeed, there are sometimes cases where you want a specific controller method to be allowed, in which case you can override the `application_controller.rb` filters in specific controllers using the `:except` or `:only` conditions.